# Switching to Ask Ubuntu no longer works

Tags: support, login

My "entry" account is SO. I can easily switch to MSE, Programmers, Mathematics.  But I can (edit:) **no longer** switch to AU. That is, the Ask Ubuntu page shows, but I am not logged in (and the system suspects me being a robot).  For reproduction, I go to my profile, and select [the link to my hp](https://askubuntu.com/users/119823/false).

For MSE, Programmers, Mathematics I am logged in as expected (as is shown in the black-bar).

---

What did work was to login manually into AU as suggested by @AnnaLear. Since then, I am logged in. Will probably take some time to see if this is a permanent solution.

Comment: On which browser do you see this? Can you repro this in another browser or in incognito mode?

Comment: @rene: ff 39.0.3. In incognito-mode I am not myself, but an anonymous user.

Comment: @rene - I am experiencing this same issue in chrome.

Comment: @Dzyann but after you're logged in on AU, you stay logged in, right?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried logging in on AU?

The other sites you listed are on the same second-level domain, so that login session is covered by the same cookie. Under some circumstances (e.g. 3rd party cookies are disabled), we may be unable to log you into all second-level domains we control.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well and I don't *think* I have 3rd party cookies disabled.

Comment: @ChrisF In what browser? What happens if you do log in on AU or another SLD you're currently "anonymous" on?

Comment: Chrome. It works - I get logged in and I stay logged in. It was just the first time it didn't automatically log me in. On all other sites I'm auto-logged-in.

Comment: @ChrisF If you have a moment to spare... can you log out (or switch to incognito), then log in on AU and check other domains (SO, SE, SU, etc.)? Do you get logged in on all?

Comment: Went incognito. Logged into AU. Went to accounts (was logged in on SE), went to SO profile was logged in.

Comment: Actually I should have said I *saw* this, as of course it's all working OK for me now. Sorry for possibly sending you down a blind alley.

Comment: Until recently, that is a week or so ago, it worked.

Comment: @false I'm gonna need more information here. Were you logged in on AU a week ago and got randomly logged out? What happens if you log in on AU again?

Comment: I was never randomly logged out.  But as of yesterday, I was not able to "log in" implicitly coming from SO. Now with an explicit login, everything is fine, but I thought the new improvements should have made this seamless. At least they do this for all the other sites I tried.

Comment: @false You never implicitly log in by coming from SO. You implicitly login *by logging in* on another domain in our network. I'll check the traffic logs and see if there's anything enlightening in there, but if you are able to log in and stay logged in, I'm inclined to chalk up this case to a fluke.

Comment: If I am logged in to Stack Overflow and go a different second-level domain like Superuser or AskUbuntu, the login page offers the option to log in with Google, Facebook, or Launchpad, --or-- email/password.  Entering the SO email/password logs me in to AU (and creates AU cookies), but the login page makes it appear as if the email/password is to create a new account (where users would want to enter a NEW password, not reuse one from SO).  Changing the login page to have an explicit "SO" option as with Google/FB would make it more obvious that the user is linking to an existing account.